# Order of deployment in 2GP

Tags: managed-package, 2gp

How can we determine the order in which the metadata is deployed?

I have developed a package which relies on EnhancedNotes and has a flow which creates EnhancedNotes. I have retrieved the metadata for enabling EnhancedNotes:

**force-app/main/default/settings/EnhancedNotes.settings-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnhancedNotesSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableEnhancedNotes>true</enableEnhancedNotes>
    <enableTasksOnEnhancedNotes>true</enableTasksOnEnhancedNotes>
</EnhancedNotesSettings>
```

When I deploy my code to a scratch org, it fails with the error `field integrity exception: unknown (The object "ContentNote" can't be created through a flow.)`.
But when I first deploy the folder containing the setting for enabling EnhancedNotes (force-app/main/default/settings) and then deploy the rest, it works fine.
So it seems there is a dependency issue (on EnhancedNotes).
While this two-step deployment works for development, when I want to create a package version, it has to be in one step, and gives the same error as above. It seems I need to instruct it in some way to first deploy the setting for enabling EnhancedNotes and then deploy the rest.

The issue is explained in [this](https://www.loom.com/share/9ed3e8ae1d214637826a5ba46952abaf?sid=3adbbae4-1157-441d-a71a-95520d32d30a) two-minute video. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings folder is completely ignored when creating a package version. You need to tell the package which dependencies should be enabled in the project configuration.

First, enable the settings, as outlined in [Scratch Org Features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm):

```
{
    "orgName": "My Org",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "settings": {
        "enhancedNotesSettings": {
            "enableEnhancedNotes": true
         }
         // Other settings, as needed
    }
}
```

Then, set up your sfdx-project.json configuration file to specify the configuration file:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
     { "path": "force-app",
       "default": true,
       "definitionFile": "./config/scratch-org.json",
       "versionName": "Latest and Greatest",
       "versionDescription": "Install it and find out!",
       "versionNumber": "1.2.3.NEXT"
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When creating a package version, I assume only certain sections of the mentioned definition file are considered. For example `"edition": "Developer"` is not taken into account, right?

Comment: @LoMaPh Correct, the orgName, edition, etc are used when creating a Scratch Org, while the settings will affect package versions.